# Windows 7 MultiTouch .NET API for Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7, multi-touch

Is there any library for multi touch capabilities of Windows 7 wrapped up for .NET?

I mean [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but with .NET flavor.

Some limitations however: I need it for DESKTOP development, and for Windows Forms, no WPF.

Comment: Have you tried searching for ".NET multi touch"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://multitouch.codeplex.com/
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch: Look for "interop sample"

BTW: WPF4 should support it out of the box:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansont/archive/2009/12/03/multi-touch-in-wpf-4-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx

Comment: microsoft site would be ok for that (interop sample)