# windows 8 tap and hold event c#

Tags: c#, windows, touch, tap

I'm trying to write an application that senses when someone taps and holds something. I am using windows forms. I tried using the mouse down even but it doesn't appear to fire all the time.  This is also going to be a multi touch application. I'm going to have two buttons , and the user can tap and hold one button, while they press on the other button. Or Just press one button. I'm not even sure how a windows form app can handle that.

All the examples inhave seen for a windows touch app use xaml. Is this really the only way to capture tap and hold ??

I'm essentially making an onscreen keyboard here, and I don't think that isnpossible WITHOUT windows forms. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Any help or guidance in this is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 MultiTouch .NET API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486818/windows-7-multitouch-net-api)

Answer (score 2):

If your program is running on Windows 8, you can use the WM_POINTER API to get the input you need. Override WndProc to capture the messages. You will have to do some P/Invoke to get it working, but it's not terribly hard. Here's some incomplete code to get you started, you'll need to add cases for up, down, and update events for each type of pointer you want to track. Keep track of the pointer IDs to process multi touch. To handle the press-and-hold you'll need to track the time yourself from WM_POINTERDOWN to WM_POINTERUP and act accordingly. Hope this helps.

```
public const int WM_POINTERDOWN = 0x0246;
public const int WM_POINTERUP = 0x0247;
public const int WM_POINTERUPDATE = 0x0245;

public enum POINTER_INPUT_TYPE : int
{
    PT_POINTER = 0x00000001,
    PT_TOUCH   = 0x00000002,
    PT_PEN     = 0x00000003,
    PT_MOUSE   = 0x00000004
}

public static uint GET_POINTERID_WPARAM(uint wParam) { return wParam & 0xFFFF; }

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetPointerType(uint pPointerID, out POINTER_INPUT_TYPE pPointerType);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    bool handled = false;
    uint pointerID;
    POINTER_INPUT_TYPE pointerType;
    switch(m.Message)
    {
        case WM_POINTERDOWN:
             pointerID = User32.GET_POINTERID_WPARAM((uint)m.WParam);
             if (User32.GetPointerType(pointerID, out pointerType))
             {
                 switch (pointerType)
                 {
                     case POINTER_INPUT_TYPE.PT_PEN:
                         // Stylus Down
                         handled = true;
                         break;
                     case POINTER_INPUT_TYPE.PT_TOUCH:
                         // Touch down
                         handled = true;
                         break;
                 }
             }
             break;
    }

    if (handled)
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for how to interpret WM_POINTER messages in C#! Thank you!

Comment: Oh wait, this'll get me the ID. But what about the coordinates?

Comment: Also, is that really how you get the ID? I thought WParam and LParam were pointers. You don't have to dereference them?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been around for a while and might benefit from a simple approach. You can simulate the "tap and hold" (or click and hold) by measuring the time between the MouseDown event and the Click event (which fires before MouseUp). If the time is greater than some value then you cancel the Click and (perhaps) fire your own TapAndHold event. I have created a test control that anyone can use to try this approach out. Just add a UserControl to your test app (I called mine TestTapAndHold) and then paste in the following:

```
public partial class TestTapAndHold : UserControl
{
    private string showText = "Tap Me";
    private DateTime mouseDown;
    private const int holdTime = 500;
    public TestTapAndHold()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += drawText;
    }
    public delegate void OnTapAndHold(EventArgs e);
    public event OnTapAndHold TapAndHold;
    private void drawText(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(showText, Font, drawBrush, new Point(5,3));
        }
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(mouseDown).Milliseconds >= holdTime)
        {
            showText = "Tap Hold";
            TapAndHold?.Invoke(e);
        } else
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
            showText = "Tapped";
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
    private void TestTapAndHold_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Build the app and then pop one of the test controls onto a form. You can then add an event handler to your form like:

```
    private void testTapAndHold1_TapAndHold(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You tapped and Held");
    }
```

This general approach enabled me to add "Tap and Hold" functionality to a Windows Forms app running on a Microsoft Surface 4